# Sort on arrays element don't work in Elasticsearch on Spring boot using java API

Tags: java, sorting, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I got problem (or lack of knowledge) in sorting documents in elasticsearch.
Elasticsearch is local and managed by spring boot. What im trying to do is to, using java API, search documents and sort them. Te docs are looking something like that (little simplified):

```
{
(...)
"relatedDocuments": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("123123"),
    (...)
    "relationSet": [{
        "type": {
            "name": "Some name",
            "version": NumberLong(1)
        },
        "documentId": "123123",
        "content": {
            "numberToSearch": "U-2016-8"<---element to sort by
        }
    }]
    (...)
}]
(...)
}
```

As you can see the element to sort by is in object which is in array which is in other object holdet by another array...

Now I'm making some query which seems to work fine but sorting... like sorting never occured... the Java code looks something like:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        //some bool query created
        boolQuery.must(query);
        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("relatedDocuments.relationSet.content.numberToSearch").order(SortOrder.ASC).sortMode("min")).withQuery(boolQuery).build();

        return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, GenericDocumentIndex.class);
```

the result is properly searched but not sorted at all...

If I change the fieldSort to something simplier like "relatedDocuments.id" then sorting work...

What is wrong here?

**EDIT**
for reference resulted rekords are sorted as below:
U-2016-5
U-2016-6
U-2016-7
U-2016-4
U-2016-8
U-2016-9
U-2016-12
U-2016-11
U-2016-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
 the issue wasn't in query or document structure but in field value...
it was dash separated so elastic search didnt keep it as whole string but as separated tokens.
Solution is to set this field (or add sub field) with index not_analyzed propertie...
In java it whould be done by adding annotetion over the field like this or similar:

```
@Field(
        type = FieldType.String,
        index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
relationSet seems like a nested field in your schema.
```

For Sorting on nested fields, you should refer to the link below

Reference : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html

```
"sort": [{
        "relatedDocuments.relationSet.content.numberToSearch": {
            "nested_path": "relatedDocuments.relationSet",
            "mode": "min",
            "order": "desc",
            "ignore_unmapped": false
        }
    }],
```

UPDATE :

You need to explicitly mark `relationSet` as nested via spring-boot

```
@Document(indexName = "indexName", type = "inxedType", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class RelatedDocuments {
@Field(type= FieldType.Nested)  // <-- mark it as nested
private List<Relation> relationSet;   
}
```

PS  : delete the index and recreate before proceeding

Comment: I've changed java code to:  
`SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("relatedDocuments.relationSet.content.numberToSearch").setNestedPath("relatedDocuments.relationSet.content").order(SortOrder.ASC).sortMode("min")).withQuery(safeQuery).build();`  

and it throws exception :  

`nested: QueryParsingException[[document] [nested] nested object under path [relatedDocuments.relationSet.content] is not of nested type]`

Comment: sorry.. the content field is not-nested in your case. updating the answer

Comment: still exception is the same  `nested: QueryParsingException[[document] [nested] nested object under path [relatedDocuments.relationSet] is not of nested type];`

Comment: can you share your schema mapping

Comment: I don't know what it is so propably spring is dealing with this automaticaly... is it  defined in elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes it it. You can get it using the followin curl. curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/{index_name}/_mapping/{index_type}'

Comment: ok, i've replaced some unrelevant fields: `{"document": {"mappings": {"genericdocumentindex": {"properties": {"id": {"type": "string"},(...)"relatedDocuments": {"properties": {(...)"relationSet": {"properties": {"content": {"properties": {"numberToSearch": {"type": "string"}}},"documentId": {"type": "string"},"type": {"properties": {"name": {"type": "string"},"version": {"type": "long"}}}}},"state": {(...)},"version": {"type": "long"}}},(...)}}}}}`

Comment: I was interested in the type of "relationSet" but that is not present everything else is not nested. Please provide the "type" field at the level of relationSet in the schema

Comment: there is non such field called "type" on same level as relationSet... inside relationSet there is such field but it's not added by elasticsearch, there is simply field "type" in my document...

Comment: updated the answer.. you need to explicitly make the field as nested

Comment: ok, i explicitly set nested type, nested sorting is not trowing exception anymore but... documents are still "not sorted" (rekords are mixed up like in main question)...

Comment: Are you trying to sort root level docs or the nested docs ?? relationSet is an array which contains multiple content.numberToSearch fields. The current solution is to sort Root Level docs based on the minimum value in relationSet.content.numberToSearch for each relatedDocuments. If you are trying to sort the nested docs.. then the sorting needs to be applied at the nested level.

Comment: i'm trying to sort root documents... my goal is to simply find documents  and sort finded rekords by this "numberToSearch", i didn't excpect it would be so difficult :P

Comment: Your root document contains multiple "numerToSearch" fields inside each relationSet entry. eg . Doc1:{relationSet:[content.numberToSearch:1, content.numberToSearch:2]}, Doc2 : {relationSet:[content.numberToSearch:3, content.numberToSearch:2]}. Do you want the sorted order to be Doc1 followed by Doc2 ? as min value in Doc1  for numberToSearch=1 and whereas in Doc2 is 2

Comment: yes Doc1 should be followed by Doc2 and if sort order is turned around (from ASC to DESC for example) then  Doc2 should be followed by Doc1